# CSS Scroll Animation on background image not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, css-animations

I made a page that has a background image and as the user scrolls it should zoom in and highlight different parts of the page. It works fantastic on chrome for desktop and when I do responsive view in the dev tools. However when I try on my phone it doesn't work in the slightest.

I tried to change the size of the background image as well as other things but for some reason it stays at one size and has no animation at all. [Here is the page](https://samuelragland.github.io/ImageZoom/)

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: url(./sebastian-svenson-d2w-_1LJioQ-unsplash.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-color: hsl(214, 34%, 13%);
    background-size: cover;
    animation: zoom linear;
    animation-timeline: view();
}

@keyframes zoom {
    0%,25% {
        background-size: 300%;
        background-position: center;
    }
    33% {
        background-size: 400%;
        background-position: right center;
    }
    66% {
        background-size: 400%;
        background-position: 40% center;
    }
    100% {
        background-size: 600%;
        background-position: top center;
    }
}
```

Comment: `animation-timeline: view()` is an [experimental feature](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_animation-timeline_view), it won't work everywhere.